# Neuroph in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, neural-network, libraries

I'm trying to use the Neuroph Neural Network libraries in Eclipse. The readme states:

To use Neuroph in your Java appliacation add reference to neuroph-core-x.x.jar (and all other jars you want to use), and import required classes.
All aditional 3rd party libraries that are required are available in lib folder of this distribution.

I have included neuroph-core-x.x.jar in my projects build path and have imported org.neuroph.nnet.*, org.neuroph.core.* ,org.neuroph.util.* as required. When I import all of the additional 3rd party libraries from the lib folder, I receive an error when running the Multi-Layer Perceptron sample:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/ajd/Desktop/neuroph-2.92/libs/slf4j-nop-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/ajd/Desktop/neuroph-2.92/libs/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory]
```

When I remove both of the conflicting files I receive the following error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

the program doesn't terminate but just continues to display the above error and never does anything else.

If I remove either of the conflicting files (but keep the other) then it shows no error but again just runs and never arrives at any result/output

Have I missed some additional step out?

Comment: I think it is classic case of jar shadowing, remove one of the jars and check, you cerainly have 2 versions of StaticLoggerBinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code block SLF4J tells you you have two StaticLoggerBinder implementations available - the first (NOP, which logs nothing to nowhere) is used.

You need to exclude from classpath or remove the unwanted JAR `neuroph-2.92/libs/slf4j-nop-1.7.6.jar`

Answer (score 0):

1. download and unzip slf4j-1.7.24.zip  from  https://www.slf4j.org/download.html
2. download and unzip log4j-1.2.17.zip  from  http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/logging/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.zip
3. Add jars to your project:

slf4j-api-1.7.24.jar

slf4j-log4j12-1.7.24.jar

log4j-1.2.17.jar

neuroph-core-2.93.jar

These jars are enough for MLP.